# Unauthorized error when I am providing a token with a user that is both 'administrator' and 'user'

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, jwt

[image]All that I keep getting is this error from postman and I have no clue how to fix it:

The GET request that I make is:

```java
localhost:8080/api/v1/user/5?Authorization=Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzUxMiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiIxOCIsImlhdCI6MTU4OTgwNDkxNywiZXhwIjoxNTkwMjM2OTE3fQ.s0HcsW8KsZuP6v2MRUQsDuTt8tOX3b-eUsGO4YW-kVolyeZFyGCTS4BdgItXqqkg143xoXFt-vAGUvrvquEjIQ[![enter image description here][1]][1]
```

The output is:

```
{
   "timestamp": "2020-05-18T12:39:38.405+0000",
    "status": 401,
    "error": "Unauthorized",
    "message": "You're not authorized to access this resource.",
    "path": "/api/v1/user/5"
}
```

This is my configuration in my WebConfig class:

```
   @Override
   protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

       http
               .cors()
               .and()
               .csrf()
               .disable()
               .exceptionHandling()
               .authenticationEntryPoint(unauthorizedHandler)
               .and()
               .sessionManagement()
               .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
               .and()
               .authorizeRequests()
               .antMatchers("/api/v1/auth/signin", "/api/v1/auth/register")
               .permitAll()
               .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/api/v1/user")
               .permitAll()
               .anyRequest()
               .authenticated();

       http.addFilterBefore(authenticationJwtTokenFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);

   }
```

And This is my AuthController. The methods are working fine, but I am posting it as a reference:

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = "*", maxAge = 3600)
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/v1/auth")
public class AuthController {

    RoleServiceImpl roleService;

    UserServiceImpl userService;

    PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

    AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    JwtUtils jwtUtils;

    @Autowired
    public AuthController(RoleServiceImpl roleService, UserServiceImpl userService,
                          PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder, AuthenticationManager authenticationManager,
                          JwtUtils jwtUtils) {
        this.roleService = roleService;
        this.userService = userService;
        this.passwordEncoder = passwordEncoder;
        this.authenticationManager = authenticationManager;
        this.jwtUtils = jwtUtils;
    }

    @PostMapping("/signin")
    public HttpEntity authenticate(@Valid @RequestBody LoginRequest loginRequest) {

        Authentication authentication = authenticationManager.authenticate(
                new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken
                        (loginRequest.getEmail(), loginRequest.getPassword()));

        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
        String jwt = jwtUtils.generateJwtToken(authentication);

        UserDetailsImpl userDetails = (UserDetailsImpl) authentication.getPrincipal();
        List<String> roles = userDetails.getAuthorities().stream()
                .map(item -> item.getAuthority())
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

        JwtResponse jwtResponse = new JwtResponse(jwt,
                userDetails.getId(),
                userDetails.getEmail(),
                roles);

        return ResponseEntity.ok(jwtResponse);

    }


    @PostMapping("/register")
    public HttpEntity authenticate(@Valid @RequestBody RegisterRequest registerRequest) {

        if (userService.existsByEmail(registerRequest.getEmail())) {
            throw new BadRequestException("Email already exists");
        }

        User user = UserMapper.INSTANCE.registerRequestoUser(registerRequest);

        user.setPassword(passwordEncoder.encode(user.getPassword()));

        Set<String> strRoles = registerRequest.getRoles();

        Set<Role> roles = new HashSet<>();

        if (strRoles == null) {
            Role userRole = roleService.getByName("user")
                    .orElseThrow(() -> new RuntimeException("Error: Role is not found."));
            roles.add(userRole);
        } else {
            for (String role : strRoles) {

                if (role.equals("administrator")) {
                    Role adminRole = roleService.getByName("administrator")
                            .orElseThrow(() -> new RuntimeException("Error: Role is not found."));
                    roles.add(adminRole);
                }

                if (role.equals("user")) {
                    Role userRole = roleService.getByName("user")
                            .orElseThrow(() -> new RuntimeException("Error: Role is not found."));
                    roles.add(userRole);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        user.setRoles(roles);
        userService.create(user);

        return ResponseEntity.ok("Success");
    }
}
```

Here I start to get problems. When I access some of these methods and even when I provide my token, I still get Unauthorized error.

```
@RequestMapping("/api/v1/user")
@RestController
public class UserController {

    private final UserServiceImpl userService;

    private PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

    @Autowired
    public UserController(UserServiceImpl userService, PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder) {
        this.userService = userService;
        this.passwordEncoder=passwordEncoder;
    }

    @GetMapping(value = "/{id}")
    public HttpEntity get(@PathVariable(name = "id") Long id) {
        Optional<User> userOptional = userService.get(id);

        if (userOptional.isPresent()) {
            return ResponseEntity.ok(UserMapper.INSTANCE.userToUserGetDTO(userOptional.get()));
        }
        throw new RecordNotFoundException("Invalid user id : " + id);
    }

    @GetMapping
    public HttpEntity get() {
        List<User> users = userService.get();
        List<UserGetDTO> userGetDTOS = new ArrayList<>();

        if (users.isEmpty()) {
            throw new RecordNotFoundException("No users");
        }
        for (User user : users) {
            userGetDTOS.add(UserMapper.INSTANCE.userToUserGetDTO(user));
        }
        return ResponseEntity.ok(userGetDTOS);
    }

    @PostMapping
    public HttpEntity create(@Valid @RequestBody UserPostDTO userPostDTO) {

        User user = UserMapper.INSTANCE.userPostDTOtoUser(userPostDTO);
        user.setPassword(passwordEncoder.encode(user.getPassword()));

        Optional<User> userOptional = userService.create(user);

        if (userOptional.isPresent()) {
            return ResponseEntity.ok(UserMapper.INSTANCE.userToUserGetDTO(user));
        }
        throw new BadRequestException("Unprocessable entity");
    }
```

Comment: add the screenshot from postman when you make this request

Comment: okay, i did that

Comment: did you configured filter which will parse token in each request ?

Answer (score 1):

If you can debug the code and delegate the request to spring security class, you can see the validate(actual,provided) method fails.

This occurs mainly because of mismatch in Bcrypt encoder Hashing which should start with $2a or $2x.

I would suggest to use `BCryptPasswordEncoder` in `jwtUtils.generateJwtToken(authentication)` which will defintely solve the authentication issue.  Below is the piece of code.

```
PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder = new BCryptPasswordEncoder(); 
String encodedPassword = passwordEncoder.encode(password);
```

Comment: I am using BCryptPasswordEncoder :/ Maybe I am still misunderstanding something